# PHP replace certain number of characters in string

Tags: php

I have the current code where I'm trying to mask part of user's email with ***

```
$user_email                         = info@test.com

$unmasked_user_email_array          = explode('@', $user_email);
$unmasked_user_email_string         = $unmasked_user_email[0];
$unmasked_user_email_string_length  = strlen($unmasked_user_email_string);

if ($unmasked_user_email_string_length > 4) {
    replace the last three characters of $unmasked_user_email_string with ***
}   
else if ($unmasked_user_email_string_length < 5) {
    replace the last two characters of $unmasked_user_email_string with **
}
else if ($unmasked_user_email_string_length < 4) {
    replace the last one character of $unmasked_user_email_string with *
}
```

My question is, what methods or functions should I use to be able to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thanks

Comment: Fault in your code: $unmasked_user_email_string = $unmasked_user_email[0]; should be $unmasked_user_email_string         = $unmasked_user_email_array[0];

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected that in my production code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick for you. Using php native function substr() to remove the last couple of characters. Then we rebuild the email address after appending some stars for hidden elements.
Also, your $unmasked_user_email[0] should be $unmaskd_user_email_array[0]:

```
$user_email                         = "info@test.com"

$unmasked_user_email_array          = explode('@', $user_email);
$unmasked_user_email_string         = $unmasked_user_email_array[0];
$unmasked_user_email_string_length  = strlen($unmasked_user_email_string);

if ($unmasked_user_email_string_length > 4) {
    $email = substr( $unmasked_user_email_string, 0, -4 ) . '****' . $unmasked_user_email_array[1];
}   
else if ($unmasked_user_email_string_length < 5) {
    $email = substr( $unmasked_user_email_string, 0, -2 ) . '**' . $unmasked_user_email_array[1];
}
else if ($unmasked_user_email_string_length < 4) {
    $email = substr( $unmasked_user_email_string, 0, -1 ) . '*' . $unmasked_user_email_array[1];
}
```

Php substr() manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 1):

Use the substr method of php.

```
Syntax : substr($string,$start,$length);

and substr($string,$start); to get the entire string after the "$start" position(staring from 0)
```

See : https://www.php.net/substr

So,

```
if ($unmasked_user_email_string_length > 4) {

$unmasked_user_email_string with = substr($unmasked_user_email_string,0,strlen($unmasked_user_email_string)-3);
//abc@xzy.com => abc@xyz.***

}   

else if ($unmasked_user_email_string_length < 5) {
//do it yourself

}

else if ($unmasked_user_email_string_length < 4) {
//do it yourself

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use substr ([php.net/substr](http://php.net/substr)) to cut the end of the string, and then concatenate how many * you want. For example :

```
$user_email_hidden = substr($unmasked_user_email_string, 0, $unmasked_user_email_string_length-4) . '****'
```

Comment: He said last 3 not last 4

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$user_email                         = "o1231@test.com";

$unmasked_user_email_array          = explode("@", $user_email);
$unmasked_user_email_string         = $unmasked_user_email_array[0];
$unmasked_user_email_string_length  = strlen($unmasked_user_email_string);

if ($unmasked_user_email_string_length > 4) {
    // replace the last three characters of $unmasked_user_email_string with ***
    $unmasked_user_email_string = substr($unmasked_user_email_string, 0, -3) . '***'; 
}   
else if ($unmasked_user_email_string_length == 5) {
    // replace the last two characters of $unmasked_user_email_string with **
    $unmasked_user_email_string = substr($unmasked_user_email_string, 0, -2) . '**'; 
}
else if (($unmasked_user_email_string_length < 4) && ($unmasked_user_email_string_length >= 2)) {
    // replace the last one character of $unmasked_user_email_string with *
    $unmasked_user_email_string = substr($unmasked_user_email_string, 0, -1) . '*'; 
}
else {
    // replace the last one character of $unmasked_user_email_string with *
    $unmasked_user_email_string = substr($unmasked_user_email_string, 0, -1) . '*****'; 
}
echo $unmasked_user_email_string;

?>
```